# Is the iSCSI block device having client side-read cache (if yes how to disable)?

Tags: cache, iscsi

I have a remote block device with the test ext4 filesystem image.
On the iSCSI initiator side, I have this device detected as let's say `/dev/sdb`. I am *not* mounting this filesystem but instead I use TheSleuthKit (TSK) forensic tool `fls` to read the content of my data.

I notice that for the second run the execution time indeed is faster. I know about the page cache and that to bypass it I should use Direct-IO. However, I was convinced this will not be the case for the iSCSI.

If the device is being modified by another node, there is no way for my client to see it if it has this entry cached. So it simply means - inconsistency issues. How can I ensure my reads will always go to the "source" ? Is there any parameter I can set to flush read cache periodically ?(echo 3 > /proc ... is not an option).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a block device read buffer cache -- bcache -- which caches blocks previously read.

If you do **not** want this behavior, you can open the block device with O_DIRECT flag.

Comment: Actually as I understand, `bcache` is not some default cache, it's a thing one have to configure explicitly. So it's unlikely to be the OP's problem. I'm gonna dump some of the research I've done here in comment too: after a discussion on #kernel-newbies IRC I've got an impression that nowadays *(which is 4 years since the question posted)* there's no block-device level cache. There's VFS-level cache, but it's unused if you don't have an FS over the block device. There's also `/sys/block/sdX/queue/write_cache` file, but whether it's a software or hw cache is unclear from the current docs.